# Capitalizing specific letters in a character string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm stuck on trying to figure out how to make certain letters of a character string in an array that are input as all lower case and an underscore (i.e. "first_last") output with a space between them and each beginning letter being capitalized (i.e. "First Last").

Any helpful ideas are appreciated

Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 30

int main()
{
    char string1(SIZE); //reserve a name of up to 29 characters

    //read characters from input into array string 1
    printf("%s", "Enter a name:);
    scanf("%29s", string1);
}
```

Comment: The `toupper` library function will help. The rest is just code that you need to write.

Answer (score 0):

You can just process a string character by character and modify the relevant characters, something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Capitalise based on your specs.

static void cap(char *str) {
    // No actions for empty string.

    if (*str == '\0') return;

    // Always upper first character.

    str[0] = toupper(str[0]);

    // Check all but last character (ignore trailing '_').

    for (size_t i = 1, count = strlen(str) - 1; i < count; ++i) {
        // If underscore, make space and upper next character.

        if (str[i] == '_') {
            str[i] = ' ';
            str[i+1] = toupper(str[i+1]);
        }
    }
}

// Test driver to do all arguments.

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        printf("'%s'", argv[i]);
        cap(argv[i]);
        printf("-> '%s'\n", argv[i]);
    }
}
```

You'll probably want to handle edge cases but, since you haven't specified the desired behaviour for them, I've just left them as further exercises for the reader. Things to think about are:

- how to handle string with `multiple____underscores`;
- how to treat `_` at end of string;
- how to treat `_` if *not* followed by a lower-case letter; and
- quite possibly other things I haven't thought of :-)

---

Here's a sample run so you can see it in action:

```
pax$ testprog first_second one one_two
'first_second'-> 'First Second'
'one'-> 'One'
'one_two'-> 'One Two'
```